# Implement global menu in Basic4android

Tags: menu, basic4android

I am developing an application that has many activities. Is there any way to implement the same menu to all activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code module to create the menu.

```
Sub CreateMenu(Act As Activity)
    Act.AddMenuItem("m1", "m1")
    Act.AddMenuItem("m2", "m2")
    Act.AddMenuItem("m3", "m3")
End Sub
```

You can then call this method from other activities. The events will be handled in each activity.